# Angular currency pipe without value

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe

Is it possible to use the currency pipe without actual amount/value?

Usage with value as in https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'currency-pipe',
  template: `<div>
    <!--output 'CA$0.26'-->
    <p>{{a | currency:'CAD'}}</p>
  </div>`
})
export class CurrencyPipeComponent {
  a: number = 0.259;
  b: number = 1.3495;
}
```

Output: `CA$0.26`

However, I need to input 'CAD' and output 'CA$'. Is this possible somehow?

Desired behaviour:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'currency-pipe',
  template: `<div>
    <p>{{currency | currency:'CAD'}}</p>
  </div>`
})
```

Desired Output: `CA$`

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/getCurrencySymbol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source code:

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/pipes/number_pipe.ts#L205

you'll find that pipe returns null if the input is "not a value" - if following function returns false:

```
function isValue(value: number|string|null|undefined): value is number|string {
  return !(value == null || value === '' || value !== value);
}
```

Probably, the best way to achieve your desired result is to create your own pipe. Take a look at the code of the CurrencyPipe. The most important fragment is:

```
currency = getCurrencySymbol(currency, display === 'symbol' ? 'wide' : 'narrow', locale);
```

Probably this is what you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Just a slightly different idea: do not create a custom pipe just for that limited use case. Just cut off everything that comes after the currency.

```
{{ (0 | currency:'CAD').split('0')[0] }}
```